# Prevent data table column width from changing size Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a data table with the right column width that is updated every time the "ADD" button is clicked. When an extra row is added, it automatically resizes to fit the whole main panel, despite the fact that the text fits well.

Here's my REPREX:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

this_table = data.frame(bins = c(30, 50), cb = c(T, F))

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30),
            checkboxInput("cb", "T/F"),
            actionButton("add_btn", "Add")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            DTOutput("shiny_table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    this_table <- reactiveVal(this_table)
    
    observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
        t = rbind(data.frame(bins = input$bins,
                             cb = input$cb), this_table())
        this_table(t)
    })
    

    output$shiny_table <- renderDT({
        datatable(this_table(),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list(
                      autoWidth = TRUE,
                      columnDefs = list(list(width = "40%", targets = "_all"), list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")),
                      pageLength = 23, info = FALSE, lengthMenu = 30,
                      paging = FALSE,
                      #searching = FALSE,
                      lengthChange = FALSE,
                      ordering = FALSE ))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How do you prevent that from happening so that the column width stays the same?

Comment: adding a `div` to your `mainPanel` helps:  `mainPanel(div(DTOutput("shiny_table"), style="width: 50%;"))`.

Comment: It does! But then the horizontal space between the side panel and the main panel disappears.

Comment: I'd suggest raising this as an issue with `DT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird. It looks like the `width` option disappears when a row is added. You can wrap the `DTOutput` in a `div` element with a given width, and set `margin: auto` to center it:

```
mainPanel(
  div(
    style = "width: 300px; margin: auto;",
    DTOutput("shiny_table")
  )
)
```